# Adding data to an object is thread safe when using promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a firestore cloudFunction using TS to access the fireStore DB. The function iterates all the documents inside a collection, then it gets the data from each document and finally it adds the data to a simple object. I'm not 100% sure if this operation is thread safe. If it was written in other languages I would need something like a ConcurrentHashMap. Here the source code:

```
export async function readAllDocuments(): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> {
  const result: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("test");
  const listRef = await collectionRef.listDocuments();
  const readPromises = listRef.map(async (documentRef) => {
    return documentRef.get().then((doc) => {
      result[doc.id] = doc.data(); // Is this thread safe?
    })
  });
  await Promise.all(readPromises);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is executed in a single thread so it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there are no threads, only [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) processing. But if by saying thread safe you mean to ask if that code would run without giving back a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Yes, it will run just fine, because even though you're running on an async context, the specific method `...data()` is a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be fine with the code that you have wrote. Your code is using a method that will be running synchronous on your system. Besides that, both JavaScript and Cloud Functions use asynchronous processing - which makes it easier to manage.

I would recommend you to take a look at the below documentation from Cloud Functions, about Cloud Functions and how to better use synchronous web-hook-style on your data processing.

- [Asynchronous patterns for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-async)